# gazebo simulation

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, simulation, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I want to simulate the navigation of a pioneer p3dx in Gazebo.

I can add the robot with:

```
opt/ros/electric/stacks/p2os/p2os_urdf/launch$ roslaunch pioneer3dx.gazebo.launch
```

I can control it with the keyboard with:

```
roslaunch p2os_launch teleop_keyboard.launch
```

But I'm not able to add the world to the simulation, because when I call:

```
opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/launch$ roslaunch office_world.launch
```

the robot disappear.
Any suggestion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50450/gazebo-simulation/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-12-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved modifing the file *pioneer3dx.gazebo.launch*

I changed the line:

```
<include file="$(find gazebo_worlds)/launch/empty_world.launch"/>
```

with the line:

```
<include file="$(find gazebo_worlds)/launch/office_world.launch"/>
```

And now I can move the pioneer in the simulated office world

---

Originally posted by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) with karma: 255 on 2012-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-16**:
You should not change files that are installed by system packages since they will be overwritten on updates. Instead, copy the launch file into your own ROS package where you can modify it safely.

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2012-12-17**:
Thank you Lorenz, I didn't specify it but I usually copy the files in my workspace and then change them.